# How is the LOD set in Google Earth API when NOT using KML for placemarks

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I am dynamically setting placemarks into a Google Earth instance using the GE API.

The problem I have is that the pins are very close and they force a behaviour where you must click the group of pins and they will split off. I want to remove this behaviour and have seen there is an LOD setting relating to using KML lists of locations.

I'm not using KML, but am calling the API functions to create my placemarks.

Can I still use the LOD setting in this context? Or is there any other way to change the 'grouping' behaviour of placemarks in GE?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry no, AFAIK there is absolutely no way to change the clustering/grouping behaviour of placemarks that are geographically located close together.